# How do I use the SQL Comparison Condition ANY/SOME with the DATATYPE Char

Tags: sql, db2

I'm new to SQL and I can't figure out how to use the ANY Operator with two Strings.

I want to get the results that match one of two strings.
I know that the result can be easily achieved by using IN/OR which I already did, but we were asked to do the same with ANY.

My Code looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = ANY ('ASD 357','GHJ 680')
```

I always get this error message:

> SQL0104N  An unexpected token "'ASD 357'" was found following
> "column = ANY(".  Expected tokens may include:  "".
> SQLSTATE=42601

What do I have to do to get this working?

Comment: You should use subquery for `ANY` operator. Check [link](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=subqueries-places-where-you-can-include-subquery) for tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not the `ANY`, it is the list.   You want `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column IN ('ASD 357', 'GHJ 680');
```

That is, this would also fail for an integer column:

```
WHERE column = ANY (1, 2, 3)
```

`ANY` would be fine if you had a subquery:

```
WHERE column = ANY (SELECT x FROM y)
```

Comment: Is the list with values only possible with INTEGER? Because ANY is also possible like this " SELECT empno, sal
FROM   emp
WHERE  sal > ANY (2000, 3000, 4000);" Source: [link](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/all-any-some-comparison-conditions-in-sql)

Comment: @Deno123 That link is for Oracle, not DB2. The SQL standard only defines <comp> {ANY | SOME | ALL} with a sub-query, and so does DB2 AFAIK.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I didn't know that thank you. So using ANY here would be really bad if I understand it correctly. Because I would have to use IN/OR in the subquery anyway to filter the ones I want. So I could do this in the outer query to begin with.

Comment: @Deno123 This has nothing to do with _bad_, just with trying to do something that is not defined in the syntax.

Comment: @Deno Subqueries also can be done with `VALUES` (at least in DB2), so  `WHERE column = ANY (VALUES 'ASD 357','GHJ 680')` would work. But Gordon Linoff's solution works everywhere for sure.